# how to count traffic for an image

Tags: php, logging, statistics, memcached, cdn

I'm running a site that is taking off quite well and I'd like to add something like imgur.com which is a simple stats counter for each image.

```
Submitted 9 hours ago
222,660 views · 22.61 GB bandwidth
```

Problem is, I use a CDN so I don't have any kind of logs on my server.

I was thinking to emulate this counter with memcached,

ie: every time i print the img tag for the permalink the counter will increase by one and then I can do the maths to get the bandwidth used (except for hotlinked images, but that's not the point).

The problem is that there are a lot of images and I'm not sure that memcached is the best tool, At some point I'll be forced to put memcached data on mysql or somewhere else and the fast/volatile "writes" made will be a true bottleneck at that point.

How would you tackle this, plain stats with mysql?

Comment: Do you have many images on a single page?

Comment: lots, since the mobile version shows the same image that's on the permalink. I'd like to count them while paginating so it could actually happen that I need to count 10+ images per pageview.

Comment: Why not redirect image requests with .htaccess file to a php page, which logs that the image have been requested and then the php shows the image?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with statistics and creating a lot of data, we had good results using [The BLACKHOLE Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html).

You only need a simple table with `id` (the image id), and `count` which will be used to count the number of views.

Then while loading the page, you can aggregate your image IDs and run a query like:

```
INSERT INTO image_stats (id)
VALUES($some_id)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1
```

We use this method to count page views on a high traffic site (around 600 000 daily page views ) and it's lightning fast.